# How to: ..WHERE STRTOSET(@p1), STRTOSET(@p2)

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2008

I am trying to filter a query by two (multi select) parameters.

It works fine when doing this for the first one, but complains when I add the the second one.

Is my syntax wrong is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDX WHERE has very little in common with SQL WHERE. MDX WHERE does not effect the number of rows that return, just which cube slice the cells are to be retrieved from.

I would use the FILTER function since a MDX WHERE clause must be a tuple (cell address), no more no less, i.e.,

(Dim1.Member, Dim2.Member, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @adolf: Right but you are treating it like a classic WHERE and attempting to limit what is returned. So you'd need to FILTER to do this.

Comment: Isn't a FILTER only necessary when the item in question already appears on one of the axes? also, if using FILTER, do you use it only with the column you want to filter by or do you have to put all the columns from that dimension in there and have the filter expression appearing against the column of interest? I have 3 multi select (in RS) params that I ultimately want to filter by

Comment: Am marking as answer although I'll add the caveat that I never got the chance to test it and am now working elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Tried subqueries?

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[YourMeasure]
ON COLUMNS,
    [Dimensions].[YourDimension]
ON ROWS 
FROM

(SELECT STRTOSET(@p1) ON COLUMNS FROM
(SELECT STRTOSET(@p2) ON COLUMNS FROM   

[YourCube] ) )
```

Comment: Note that this is how SSRS generates parameters, so try making some queries in the graphic designer then change to MDX view.